# Explanation of solution from choco solver

Tags: java, constraint-programming, choco

When i run my choco solver 4.0.6 I get this kind of solution :

```
Solution : X = 10, Y = 14, REIF_1=1, not(REIF_1)=0, REIF_2=1, not(REIF_2)=0,  IV_3=2, REIF_4=1, not(REIF_4)=0 ...
```

Except the values of X and Y, can someone tell me what do the rest of the solution mean ?

Comment: Unless you give us the entire code, the best answer for the rest of the Output that you are getting is, that it is coming from Santa Claus.

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation for the tool you are using.

Comment: `REIF_1` much probably is the result of the first [reified constraint](http://choco-tuto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/202.objects.html#reifying-a-constraint), `REIF_2` of the second one, `IV_3` mostly the value of an unnamed variable added to the model...

Answer (score 0):

IV meqns introduced variable.
Often when constraint need auxiliary variable to work.
REIF variable are the reified variable.
The annotation in the front like not are the logical operators.

Bests

You can find the documentation https://github.com/chocoteam/choco-solver

Comment: as of my testing "IV_" is used for unnamed `IntVar`, not "introduced variable" - same as `BoolVar` using "BV_", `RealVar` "RV_" ... code of `IvariableFactory` (implemented by `Model`) seconds that

Answer (score 0):

To be more accurate, the other variables have been either:
- introduced by the solver (e.g. via reformulation, reification or some views) => you should not care about them.
OR
- introduced by you but without name (a name is automatically generated in that case) => you would better give them a name if you want to print them

I also suggest you to print directly the variables you want instead of relying on the default log.